# Naive bayes classifer from scratch in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I wrote a simple naive bayes classifer for my toy dataset

```
                 msg  spam
0  free home service     1
1      get free data     1
2  we live in a home     0
3    i drive the car     0
```

Full code

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = {'msg':['free home service','get free data','we live in a home','i drive the car'],'spam':[1,1,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)

def word_counter(word_list):
    words = []
    for x in word_list:
        for i in x:
            words.append(i)
    
    word_count = Counter(words)
    return word_count

spam = [x.split() for x in set(df['msg'][df['spam']==1])]
spam = word_counter(spam)

ham = [x.split() for x in set(df['msg'][df['spam']==0])]
ham = word_counter(ham)

total = len(spam.keys())+len(ham.keys())

# Prior
spam_prior = len(df['spam'][df['spam']==1])/len(df)
ham_prior = len(df['spam'][df['spam']==0])/len(df)

new_data = ["get free home service","i live in car"]
print("\n\tSpamminess")
for msg in new_data:
    data = msg.split()
    
    # Likelihood
    spam_likelihood = 0.001 # low value to prevent divisional error
    ham_likelihood = 0.001
    for i in data:
        if i in spam:
            if spam_likelihood==0.001:
                spam_likelihood = spam[i]/total
                continue
            spam_likelihood = spam[i]/total * spam_likelihood
        if i in ham:
            if ham_likelihood==0.001:
                ham_likelihood = ham[i]/total
                continue
            ham_likelihood = ham[i]/total * ham_likelihood
    
    # marginal likelihood
    marginal = (spam_likelihood*spam_prior) + (ham_likelihood*ham_prior)
    
    spam_posterior = (spam_likelihood*spam_prior)/marginal
    print(msg,round(spam_posterior*100,2))
```

The problem is it failed completely in my `Spamminess` classification for unseen data.

```
get free home service 0.07
i live in car 97.46
```

I expected high value for `get free home service` and low value for `i live in car`.

My question is if this error is due to lack of additional data or its because of my coding error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code. The likelihood is computed incorrectly.
See [Wikipedia:Naive_Bayes_classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) for the right formula for the likelihood under the bag-of-words model.

Your code works as if the likelihood p(word | spam) is 1 when the word wasn't previously encountered in spam. With Laplace smoothing, it should be 1 / (spam_total + 1), where spam_total in the total number of words in spam (with repetition).

When the word was previously encountered in spam x times, it should be (x + 1) / (spam_total + 1).

I've changed the Counter to defaultdict to conveniently deal with words that weren't encountered before, fixed the likelihood calculation and added Laplace smoothing:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'msg':['free home service','get free data','we live in a home','i drive the car'],'spam':[1,1,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)

def word_counter(sentence_list):
    word_count = defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for sentence in sentence_list:
        for word in sentence:
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count

spam = [x.split() for x in set(df['msg'][df['spam']==1])]
spam_total = sum([len(sentence) for sentence in spam])
spam = word_counter(spam)

ham = [x.split() for x in set(df['msg'][df['spam']==0])]
ham_total = sum([len(sentence) for sentence in ham])
ham = word_counter(ham)

# Prior
spam_prior = len(df['spam'][df['spam']==1])/len(df)
ham_prior = len(df['spam'][df['spam']==0])/len(df)

new_data = ["get free home service","i live in car"]
print("\n\tSpamminess")
for msg in new_data:
    data = msg.split()
    
    # Likelihood
    spam_likelihood = 1
    ham_likelihood = 1
    for word in data:
        spam_likelihood *= (spam[word] + 1) / (spam_total + 1)
        ham_likelihood *= (ham[word] + 1) / (ham_total + 1)
    
    # marginal likelihood
    marginal = (spam_likelihood * spam_prior) + (ham_likelihood * ham_prior)
    
    spam_posterior = (spam_likelihood * spam_prior) / marginal
    print(msg,round(spam_posterior*100,2))
```

Now the results are like expected:

```
    Spamminess
get free home service 98.04
i live in car 20.65
```

This can be further improved, e.g. for numerical stability the multiplication of all these probabilities should be replaced by adding logarithms.

Comment: What is `spam_total = len(spam)` do? I assume we want number of words but its giving number of sentences.